# how to overlay a div with an transparent input?

Tags: css, html

i am building a small upload element.

it is a div (in reality a vue / quasar card but i guess this does not matter) that is responsive and grows and shrinks depending on the window size and viewport.

it contains a form which holds an input and an other div

**problem:**

the input should be transparent and only provide functionality. i want the other div to lay exactly under it and show an icon and text. both, input and inner div, should fill the enclosing element completely

**what i have tried so far:**

setting 
`positions: absolute` and `relative`, using `z-index`.
when the position was relative, setting width and height to 100% worked, but the elements were next to each other. when using an absolute position, the overlays worked but but the input element became much bigger than its parent.
i can not set its size directly..

```html
<div style="width: 500px; height: 400px; background-color: #990000">  <!-- actually a card from the vue / quasar framework -->
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" style="height: 100%">
    <div class="justify-center column" style="height:100%">
      <input type="file" multiple :name="uploadFieldName" :disabled="isSaving" @change="filesChange()" style="align-content: center; opacity: 0.5; /* invisible but it's there! */
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;">
      <div class="justify-center column" style="height: 100%; background-color: #009900;">
        <q-icon name="add" size="40px" color="secondary" class="q-pa-md" />
        <p class="text-secondary no-padding no-margin" style="font-size: 12px">drop documents here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ywNVYB

thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: paste code in the question - not as a link. Also, this has been asked 1000s of times on SO .. just do some googling fiirst

Comment: FYI Opaque is the opposite of transparent; which I suspect is what you actually meant.

Comment: thanks @treyBake - i changed it.
i have researched and tried to adapt the solutions i found for several hours now (most of them setting the width of the overlaying elements directly to 1304px or sth - if you make an overlay over an image you know its size..) but i could not get it to work. i would not have ask if i had not tried it on my own before..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your problem correctly - then you should create label for your input, hide input and style label the way you want. Connect label and input by id and for, then you will be able to upload files clicking on label

here's an example

```css
[type=file] {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
}

label {
 background-color: gold;
 width: 250px;
 height: 50px;
 border-radius: 8px;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
}

label span {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

[type=file]:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<label for='input1'>
  <span>click me or drag your files here</span>
  <input id='input1' type='file'>
</label>
```

Comment: I just realized that this does remove the drag&drop functionality.. only the input reacts to it, not the label..

Comment: @leo I edited my answer so you can keep drag&drop functionality